# How to extract an attachment from an email header?

Tags: downloads, email

I recently got an e-mail with an attached JAR file. However, my e-mail client considers it malware and is not letting me open it.

I've opened the actual e-mail, and found the attachment, which seems to be encoded in Base64. How would I take this and turn it back into a Jar file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you've isolated the part of the email containing the base64-encoded file, the process for decoding the file is as follows:

```
base64 --decode < [in_filename] > [out_filename]
```

...where `[in_filename]` is the name of the file containing the base64-encoded data and `[out_filename]` is the name of the file that will contain the decoded results.

For the curious, the `base64` command is provided by the [coreutils [image: Install coreutils]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/coreutils) package, which is considered an essential package and therefore [should always be available](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-binary.html#s3.8).

Comment: That just prints the decoded version, so do I just put that output into a file then by making it `base64 --decode < [filename] > file.jar` instead?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda Yep.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda fixed.

Answer (score 2):

The `uuencode` / `uudecode` sisters are exactly what you want (to install do `sudo apt-get install sharutils`).

1. Start by extracting the Base64 text from the attachment. Save it somewhere (for the example, it'll be at `~/attachment.jar.b64`).
2. Open up a shell (and if necessary, `cd` to the right directory)
3. Run the below command to actually turn it into a Jarfile:

   ```
   uudecode -o attachment.jar attachment.jar.b64
   ```
4. Enjoy!

Comment: I get this error: `uudecode fatal error:
attachment.jar.b64: Invalid or missing 'begin'`.

Comment: But the jar file still seems to have been created, is that fine?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda Check if the file works. That's the easiest way to test.

Comment: It doesn't and has a different checksum from the file I get from using Nathan's method.

Comment: Is there a step that you missed out perhaps? Or something else that needs to be in the file? I mean what does the error message mean by `'begin'`?